# Need a Map Compare Tool for Non-Public Styles

Tags: maps, openstreetmap

Does anyone have pointers on or can point me too a codebase to create a map compare tool for Non-Public Styles? I want to compare multiple maps besides the available mapbox styles.

Here is the example of one for public styles:
https://tools.geofabrik.de/mc/#15/49.0094/8.3902&num=4&mt0=mapnik&mt1=geofabrik-basic-colour&mt2=mapnik-german&mt3=here-map

I have not attempted to create this but would like to.